# How to kill all recursive children of process windows

Tags: windows, api, recursion, process, pid

I have a question but no solution.

My program run and create some processes,but processes go on creating another processes.
I don't know how to get all children to kill all.

I used `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function to get all children whose parent is my program(mainthread) ... and go on getting all children from each children of mainthread.

```
hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
```

If I use this solution,performance is very low because I had PID of all processes in the first time,so I couldn't need to call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` again

Which best solution can I do to  get all recursive children of process windows   ?

Comment: Do you want to kill all child processes when (and because) your first process terminates?

Comment: Hi @quanrock Please give feedback. Did you managed to use Jobs, or to use my code?

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look at the [Win32 Job API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx). One functionality is the ability to automatically terminate all process belonging to the same Job. See the [TerminateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686709.aspx) API.

EDIT: Mr Chen just blogged about that precise subject. [Destroying all child processes (and grandchildren) when the parent exits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/12/09/10474855.aspx)

Then, your question. You could build a std::map of all the currently running process, the key being the PID, and the values being a std::vector of child processes. You can then recursion on the map to terminate a process and all his children.

```
// KillChildren.cpp
// Usage: pass a PID a argument

#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<DWORD> VEC_CHILDS;
typedef VEC_CHILDS::iterator IT_CHILDS;
typedef std::map<DWORD, VEC_CHILDS> MAP_PIDS;
typedef MAP_PIDS::iterator IT_PIDS;

void KillProcess( DWORD dwPID ) {

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, dwPID );
    if ( hProcess == NULL ) {
        printf( "Cant't OpenProcess for PID %u, Reason %u\n", dwPID, GetLastError() );
        return;
    }
    BOOL bWin32Success = TerminateProcess( hProcess, 0 );
    if ( bWin32Success == 0 ) {
        printf( "Cant't TerminateProcess for PID %u, Reason %u\n",
                dwPID, GetLastError() );
    } else {
        DWORD dwRetVal = WaitForSingleObject( hProcess, 2000 );
        if ( dwRetVal != WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) {
            printf( "Failed to Wait for Process Termination for PID %u,"
                    "RetVal %u Reason %u\n", dwPID, dwRetVal, GetLastError() );
        } else {
            printf( "Process %u Terminated\n", dwPID );
        }
    }
    CloseHandle( hProcess );

}

void KillChilds( DWORD dwParentPID, MAP_PIDS & mPids ) {
    IT_PIDS it = mPids.find( dwParentPID );
    if ( it == mPids.end() ) return;
    VEC_CHILDS & vChilds = it->second;
    for ( IT_CHILDS itChild = vChilds.begin(); itChild != vChilds.end(); ++itChild ) {
        KillChilds( *itChild, mPids );
    }
    KillProcess( dwParentPID );
}

// usage: PID as first arg
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    if ( argc <= 1 ) return -1;
    DWORD dwPID = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );

    HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    if ( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) return -1;

    // build PID list with children
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
    if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) ) {
        CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
        return -1;
    }
    MAP_PIDS mPids;
    do {
        // Add as a Parent, with no child, yet, if not already done
        IT_PIDS it = mPids.find( pe32.th32ProcessID );
        if ( it == mPids.end() ) mPids[ pe32.th32ProcessID ] = VEC_CHILDS();
        // Process the Parent
        it = mPids.find( pe32.th32ParentProcessID );
        if ( it == mPids.end() ) {
            // unknown parent, add it with one child
            VEC_CHILDS vChilds;
            vChilds.push_back( pe32.th32ProcessID );
            mPids[ pe32.th32ParentProcessID ] = vChilds;
        } else {
            // Parent already here, add one more child
            it->second.push_back( pe32.th32ProcessID );
        }
    } while ( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );

    KillChilds( dwPID, mPids );
    return 0;

}
```

If you want to test the above program, here is a small Process Tree generator

```
// CreateChildren.cpp
// beware, messing may be 'fork bombing'

#include <Windows.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    srand( GetTickCount() );
    // always childs if args
    if ( argc == 0 ) {
        int iRandom = rand();
        if ( iRandom % 3 ) Sleep( INFINITE );
    }

    char szFullExeName[ MAX_PATH ];
    DWORD dwCopied = GetModuleFileName( NULL, szFullExeName, sizeof( szFullExeName ) );
    if ( dwCopied == 0 ) return -1;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset( &si, 0, sizeof( si ) );
    si.cb = sizeof( si );
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    int ChildCount = rand() % 3;
    while ( ChildCount-- ) {
        BOOL bWin32Success = CreateProcess( szFullExeName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );
        if ( bWin32Success ) {
            CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
            CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        }
    }

    Sleep( INFINITE );
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Using jobs is the way to solve this. Enumerating via snapshots can leave gaps when some processes terminate early (breaking the chain). And there is no guarantee that new processes won't reuse the old PID.

Comment: @joshpoley I agree 100%.