# CBT_CREATEWND structure has invalid name

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

This is my hooking procedure, when ever i try to read the name stored in the `CBTHOOKCREATE->lpcs->lpszName` it confront with rubbish values such as :

```
79 77A064700 Created!~ 
0 00F915BC0 Created!~ 
68 000DF5BC0 Created!~ 
0 00F915BC0 Created!~ 
0 00F915BC0 Created!~ 
67 7630D8200 Created!~ 
77 000DEF340 Created!~ 
79 77A064700 Created!~
```

The same thing applies to `lpszClass`.
Is there anything that i should have done, and have not done yet regarding dereferencing lparam !?
This is the function in question:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{

    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wparam, lparam);

    std::ofstream outfile;
    CBT_CREATEWND   *CBTHOOKCREATE;
    RECT            *CBTRECTPTR;
    RECT            CBTRECT;
    wstring         Message;

    CBTHOOKCREATE = (CBT_CREATEWND*) lparam;
    LPWSTR str = L"                     ";
    outfile.open(("d:\\test.txt"), std::ios_base::app);

    if (nCode >= 0) {
        switch (nCode)
        {
        case HCBT_CREATEWND:
            outfile << *(CBTHOOKCREATE->lpcs->lpszName) << " " << CBTHOOKCREATE->lpcs->lpszName << " Created!~ " << endl;
            //cout << "Created!~" << endl;
            break;
        case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
            outfile << "Destroied!~" << endl;
            //cout << "Destroied!~" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            //cout << "sth else" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**Try to use [IsWindowUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529.aspx) with the Window Handle in `wParam`.
If the Window is an Unicode one, `lpcs` point to an `CREATESTRUCTW` structure and `lpszName` points to a wide string, that you will have to convert.

Add following code to the top of your DLL CPP file.

```
std::string wc2s( const wchar_t * pw ) {
    int length = (int)wcslen( pw ) + 1;
    int newlen = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, 0, pw, length, 0, 0, 0, 0 ); 
    std::string r( newlen , '\0' );
    WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, 0, pw, length, &r[0], newlen, 0, 0 ); 
    return r;
}
```

Use following code for the text passed to CreateWindow

```
case HCBT_CREATEWND: {
    CBT_CREATEWND * pCBT_CW = (CBT_CREATEWND *)lParam;
    std::string strCreatText;
    if ( pCBT_CW->lpcs->lpszName != NULL ) {
        if ( IsWindowUnicode( (HWND)wParam ) ) {
            strCreatText = wc2s( pCBT_CW->lpcs->lpszName );
        } else {
            strCreatText = (char*)pCBT_CW->lpcs->lpszName;  
        }
    }
    outfile << strCreatText << " Created!~ " << endl;
    break;
}
```

PS: *untested*

**UPDATE**: As per IInspectable comment. Non intrusive CBT_HOOK must follow the general rule for hooks: return what [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974.aspx) returns.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, [...]

    if ( nCode >= 0 ) {

        [...]

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wparam, lparam);

}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but this doesnt work! apart from that this makes my explorer.exe to crash each time i install the hook: here is the code : http://pastebin.com/X63H7zX8

Comment: It crash because you casted lparam to CREATESTRUCTW*. Wait for updated answer.

Comment: Two more points that need to be fixed with the original code (not yours): `1` `HookProcedure` should **always** invoke `CallNextHookEx` - the `return 0;` statement will break other code. `2` `lpszClass` is not necessarily a pointer to a string; it can be a class `ATOM` as well and needs to be checked.

Comment: @IInspectable  For your first point, I think CBT_HOOK are "specials". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx For the second point, he wants to log lpszName, not lpszClass

Comment: CBT hooks aren't special. The rules called out in [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) with respect to chaining still hold. The rules for return values of [`CBTProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) only apply, if you want to actively participate in window creation. For non-intrusive monitoring you should always invoke `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: @manuell: Thanks alot, now i have names instead of numbers but there are couple of issues. the first one is that the line : 
strCreatText = pCBT_CW->lpcs->lpszName;
doesnt compile. i had to comment it. 
The second one is that i dont get the processes names! i get something like : 
`Default IME  is Created!` 
opening new applications will not add any name to the file (may it be because of the line i commented? )
again thanks for the great job, i really really appreciate it

Comment: @Hossein Please give the compiler error for the commented line. I can't guess. Process Names and Window Texts are not the same thing, at all. I don't know why you thought you will get process name in the CREATESTRUCT.

Comment: @manuell:It gives this error:
`error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'LPCWSTR' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`
And i want the process names, i searched and found out that for having control on process executions i need to use hooks and from that i need to use CBT hook! so i went for that. 
So what should i do to be able to capture all kind of processes both those which has a window and those who are running invisible at the background?
Thanks again for everything:)

Comment: @Hossein First problem: is your DLL project compiled with Character Set set to "Unicode", or "Multi-byte", or "Not set"?

Comment: I have no idea! how can i know it?

Comment: @Hossein :-) Right clikc on the project, choose Properties, then General under Configuration Properties then look at Character Set under Project Defaults

Comment: @Hossein If you want to detect creation of NON windowed process, CBT_HOOK is USELESS. What do you want to do, EXACTLY?

Comment: Going to lunch, see you later

Comment: I want to check every single process is to be executed against a whitelist so that if it is not in that white list i terminate it.

Comment: @Hossein See updated answer for Window Creation text. Should compile and works fine now. See you tomorrow for your process problem. Bye.

Comment: Thanks alot, it compiles just fine, but still i only get these logs:
`OleMainThreadWndName  is Created!
OLEChannelWnd  is Created!
OleMainThreadWndName  is Created!
  is Created!
Default IME  is Created!
  is Created!
  is Created!
CicMarshalWnd  is Created!
MSCTFIME UI  is Created!
 is Created!
Default IME  is Created!`

Comment: I answered to your question, which was about getting the lpszName field and logging it.

Comment: As for white listing Process Creation, it's a whole different story (very bad idea, if you ask me). Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469327/how-to-kill-all-recursive-children-of-process-windows for how to use the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot API

Comment: What exactly is changed from last time ? casting to char* doesnt help in getting more names, i just still get names like i said in my last comment.
By the way i saw the link you posted,thanks, but as the last guy commented, its not real-time, and i need a real time solution for this, so that i dont miss any kind of process execution.

Comment: You had to comment out a line, because my code was for ANSI. I updated the code for UNICODE, and now it prints all names. I don't understand your "real-time/don't miss" problem. You should post a question on SO, but be careful: explain what you want, why you want it, and what you have tried so far, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: I still dont get meaningful names, just some generic names as i have already mentioned, i might record a video clip to show you that.any way, here is my new question about what i am really looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642925/how-to-monitor-process-execution-in-windows

Comment: @Hossein You can't change the question after answer is done. I spent some time trying to help you, and the code correctly prints the Window Creation Text. I don't really know WHY you thought that you would get a process name. Disapointed.

Comment: I create a video to show you what i get. here watch this : http://sdrv.ms/1bVane3 
Thanks again for the time you kindly put to help me :)

Comment: Sorry, my Windows Media PLayer is unable to play the AVI. Anyway, why  video? You sill have a bug in the above code?